# Convert to CSV based on headers position

Tags: awk, export-to-csv

I have the following text file with fields separated with spaces and in some lines some fields are empty.

```
DISTRIBUTION       MINIMUM_SYSTEM_REQUIREMENTS          BASED_ON         IMAGE_SIZE               LATEST_RELEASE_YEAR     FOUNDER              
------------------ ------------------------------------ ---------------- ------------------------ ----------------------- -------------------- 
Absolute Linux     CPU: Intel/AMD 64bit RAM: 64 MB      Slackware                                 2020                    Absolute Linux Team
Alpine Linux       RAM: 128MB                           BusyBox, musl                             2022                    LEAF Project members
antiX              CPU: Intel/AMD X86, RAM 256MB                         700 MB Base, 1GB Full    2020                    Anticapitalista
```

I'd like to add `,` or `|` as separator based on the beginning position of each header, since if I replace with a regex, more than 2 spaces with `|`, then the empty fields become in incorrect position or I get incorrect number of fields.

What I tried so far is read the first line and store all headers within an array. But currently, I'm getting wrong headers position.

```
headers=("DISTRIBUTION" "MINIMUM SYSTEM REQUIREMENTS" "BASED ON" "IMAGE SIZE" "LATEST RELEASE YEAR" "FOUNDER")
firstline=$(head -n 1 input.txt)

for w in "${headers[@]}"; do
  echo $firstline| grep -b -o "$w"
done

0:DISTRIBUTION
13:MINIMUM SYSTEM REQUIREMENTS
41:BASED ON
50:IMAGE SIZE
61:LATEST RELEASE YEAR
81:FOUNDER
```

I'm getting the headers positions `0,13,41,50,61,81` and the correct is `0,20,57,74,99,123`.

May be someone could help me with this in bash or with awk that I think could be easier but don't know how to implement it. Thanks

The output I'm looking for would be like below

```
DISTRIBUTION       |MINIMUM SYSTEM REQUIREMENTS         |BASED ON        |IMAGE SIZE              |LATEST RELEASE YEAR    |FOUNDER
-------------------|------------------------------------|-- -------------|------------------------|-----------------------|-------------------- 
Absolute Linux     |CPU: Intel/AMD 64bit RAM: 64 MB     |Slackware       |                        |2020                   |Absolute Linux Team
Alpine Linux       |RAM: 128MB                          |BusyBox, musl   |                        |2022                   |LEAF Project members
antiX              |CPU: Intel/AMD X86, RAM 256MB       |                |700 MB Base, 1GB Full   |2020                   |Anticapitalista
```

**UPDATE**

Outputs for the kind solutions provided.

*markp's output*

```
DISTRIBUTION      |MINIMUM_SYSTEM_REQUIREMENTS         |BASED_ON        |IMAGE_SIZE              |LATEST_RELEASE_YEAR    |FOUNDER              
------------------|------------------------------------|----------------|------------------------|-----------------------|-------------------- 
Absolute Linux    |CPU: Intel/AMD 64bit RAM: 64 MB  |   Slackware    |                        |   2020                |   Absolute Linux Team
Alpine Linux      |RAM: 128MB                         | BusyBox, musl |                        |  2022                 |  LEAF Project members
antiX             |CPU: Intel/AMD X86, RAM 256MB      |                | 700 MB Base, 1GB Full |  2020                 |  Anticapitalista
```

*Ed Morton's output:*

```
DISTRIBUTION      |MINIMUM_SYSTEM_REQUIREMENTS         |BASED_ON        |IMAGE_SIZE              |LATEST_RELEASE_YEAR    |FOUNDER             ||
------------------|------------------------------------|----------------|------------------------|-----------------------|--------------------||
Absolute Linux    |CPU: Intel/AMD 64bit RAM: 64 MB  |   Slackware    |                        |   2020                |   Absolute Linux Te||
Alpine Linux      |RAM: 128MB                         | BusyBox, musl |                        |  2022                 |  LEAF Project memb||s
antiX             |CPU: Intel/AMD X86, RAM 256MB      |                | 700 MB Base, 1GB Full |  2020                 |  Anticapitalista||
```

*kvantour's output*

```
DISTRIBUTION       |MINIMUM_SYSTEM_REQUIREMENTS          |BASED_ON         |IMAGE_SIZE               |LATEST_RELEASE_YEAR     |FOUNDER              
Absolute Linux     |CPU: Intel/AMD 64bit RAM: 64 MB   |   Slackware     |                         |   2020                 |   Absolute Linux Tea|m
Alpine Linux       |RAM: 128MB                          | BusyBox, musl  |                         |  2022                  |  LEAF Project membe|r
antiX              |CPU: Intel/AMD X86, RAM 256MB       |                 | 700 MB Base, 1GB Full  |  2020                  |  Anticapitalista
```

*tshiono' output*

```
DISTRIBUTION      |MINIMUM SYSTEM REQUIREMENTS         |BASED ON        |IMAGE SIZE              |LATEST RELEASE YEAR    |FOUNDER
------------------|------------------------------------|-- -------------|------------------------|-----------------------|-------------------- 
Absolute Linux    |CPU: Intel/AMD 64bit RAM: 64 MB  |   Slackware    |                        |   2020                |   Absolute Linux Team
Alpine Linux      |RAM: 128MB                         | BusyBox, musl |                        |  2022                 |  LEAF Project members
antiX             |CPU: Intel/AMD X86, RAM 256MB      |                | 700 MB Base, 1GB Full |  2020                 |  Anticapitalista
```

Differences in last field (note, didn't let me show the image, only the link)

[Differences in last field.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WRw2U.png)

Comment: Quote as `echo "$firstline" | ..` then add 1 to each value (except for the first 0).

Comment: Running `base64 -d sample.txt` shows blanks between the `---`s on the 2nd line, not `.`s as you show in the sample input at the top of your question. Is that sample input wrong? If so, [edit] your question to fix it.

Comment: `base64 -d sample.txt` shows totally different set of names such as:
`NAME`, `ADDRESS`, `PHONE` than the posted header line, Have you send
a wrong file?

Comment: @EdMorton Not sure where that dot between the `---` came from. I fixed the input and tried all the solutions (below UPDATE in my question). Only markp-fuso's and tshiono's output shows correct answer based on fixed input. but markp-fusos handles dynamycally the thing. The others, inserts `|` in some wrong position where should be a letter. Thanks for your help

Comment: @markp-fusos answer is identical to mine except they're doing the `ength()`s calculation on the array that's the result of `split(dashes line)` every time a line is read where as I'm just doing it once when that `---`s line is read so I can't imagine why you see different results from each. Frankly, I don't believe it. Also, all of the output in your answer is identical which confirms the 2 tools do not produce different output.

Comment: Not sure why is showing different outputs, you can see the differences in last field. I show an image below UPDATE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One `awk` idea where we replace characters with pipes:

```
awk '
function addpipe(line) {

    offset=0

    for (i=1;i<n;i++) {               # loop through separator array using lengths to break line into chunks and piece back together with a pipe
        line= substr(line,1,offset+length(a[i])) "|" substr(line,offset+length(a[i])+2)
        offset=offset + length(a[i]) +1
    }

    print line
}

FNR==1 { header=$0; next }
FNR==2 { n=split($0,a,".")            # split separator line on periods
         addpipe(header)
       }
       { addpipe($0) }
' file
```

This generates:

```
DISTRIBUTION      |MINIMUM SYSTEM REQUIREMENTS         |BASED ON        |IMAGE SIZE              |LATEST RELEASE YEAR    |FOUNDER
------------------|------------------------------------|-- -------------|------------------------|-----------------------|--------------------
Absolute Linux    |CPU: Intel/AMD 64bit RAM: 64 MB     |Slackware       |                        |2020                   |Absolute Linux Team
Alpine Linux      |RAM: 128MB                          |BusyBox, musl   |                        |2022                   |LEAF Project members
antiX             |CPU: Intel/AMD X86, RAM 256MB       |                |700 MB Base, 1GB Full   |2020                   |Anticapitalista
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I've tried with a sample file that has 11 fields and 50 records and prints output but without the |, not sure what happens.

Comment: probably some attribute of your file that's not coming through in the sample ... character set? non-printing characters, ??? some (initial) debugging ideas: `file input.txt`, `head -2 file.txt | od -c`, `head -2 file.txt | xxd`

Comment: What I see is that the file is in ANSI since has latin characters

Comment: If Ed Morton's suggestion (`LC_ALL=C  awk ...`) doesn't work then I'd need to see the actual contents of the problematic file; one idea that may work: `head -3 file.txt | base64` and then cut-n-paste the entire `base64` output into the question; we should then be able to cut-n-paste this into our environment and run `base64 -d` to recreate the file.

Comment: I know all your kind solutions provided work for you, but the data is kind of sensitive and If modify the original file not sure if error would be reproduced. The only solution that seems to work is the one shared by David C Rankin, but it has FIELDWIDTHS with fixed values, so I think I need to find a way to get those field widths dynamycally.

Comment: can you provide just the first 2 lines (the header and dashes)? I'm assuming those shouldn't contain any sensitive data ... yes? no? the 2 'dynamic field' answers (Ed Morton, mine) need to parse the 2nd line (dashes) so at a minimum we would need to see the 2nd line ... adding the 1st line would be helpful as it would allow use to verify the the placement of the pipes; so ... is `head -2 file.txt | base64` an option?

Comment: I've added the output of ` head -2 input.txt | base64 > sample.txt` below update in original post. Thanks for your help.

Comment: `base64 -d sample.txt` shows the column separator for the 2nd line (dashes) is a blank, but in the sample provided with the original question the column separator is a period (`.`) which in turn would explain why you're not seeing the desired results from my answer (ie, I'm parsing based on a period and not a space); please review your actual data file and update the question accordingly; also consider running `head -2 input.txt | od -c` to verify the separator in the 2nd line is in fact a period (or space? or something else?)

Answer (score 2):

You can get really close with GNU awk using `FIELDWIDTHS` to process the input as fixed width fields. To do so, you provide in the `BEGIN` rule a space separate string containing the width of each field you want to process. To get your separator, you can insert (`sub()`) a `'|'` as the new first character. You can do that with:

```bash
awk '
  BEGIN { FIELDWIDTHS = "19 37 17 25 24 8" } 
  { for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) sub(/^/,"|",$i) }1
' file
```

**Output**

Using the above on your sample data in `file`, you would receive:

```
DISTRIBUTION        |MINIMUM SYSTEM REQUIREMENTS           |BASED ON          |IMAGE SIZE                |LATEST RELEASE YEAR      |FOUNDER
------------------. |------------------------------------. |-- -------------. |------------------------. |-----------------------. |--------------------
Absolute Linux      |CPU: Intel/AMD 64bit RAM: 64 MB       |Slackware         |                          |2020                     |Absolute Linux Team
Alpine Linux        |RAM: 128MB                            |BusyBox, musl     |                          |2022                     |LEAF Project members
antiX               |CPU: Intel/AMD X86, RAM 256MB         |                  |700 MB Base, 1GB Full     |2020                     |Anticapitalista
```

The only difference I see is the `'.'` character isn't replaced by another `'-'`. Not knowing whether that is critical, this looks like it will satisfy your needs. Let me know if it need adjusting.

Also note `FIELDWIDTHS` is provided by GNU awk (`gawk`) and not `awk` itself.

---

If you wanted to ensure the `-----` field extends the entire width of the field, you can add an additional rule to replace `'.'` and `' '` with `'-'`, e.g.

```bash
awk '
  BEGIN { FIELDWIDTHS = "19 37 17 25 24 20" } 
  { for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) sub(/^/,"|",$i) } 
  /^-/ {gsub(/(\.| )/,"-") }1
' file
```

**Output**

```
DISTRIBUTION        |MINIMUM SYSTEM REQUIREMENTS           |BASED ON          |IMAGE SIZE                |LATEST RELEASE YEAR      |FOUNDER
--------------------|--------------------------------------|------------------|--------------------------|-------------------------|--------------------
Absolute Linux      |CPU: Intel/AMD 64bit RAM: 64 MB       |Slackware         |                          |2020                     |Absolute Linux Team
Alpine Linux        |RAM: 128MB                            |BusyBox, musl     |                          |2022                     |LEAF Project members
antiX               |CPU: Intel/AMD X86, RAM 256MB         |                  |700 MB Base, 1GB Full     |2020                     |Anticapitalista
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, the issue is the fields are not fixed in those positions and the file could have more or less fields. Then it seems is needed a way to get dynamically the positions of beginning of each header.

Comment: That's doable, but gets messy. You can define the separators as what the fields are are not, but this gets messy quick. You have to take care not to modify a field which would cause `awk` to recalculate the field losing whitespace (or separators) and corrupting the dynamic calculation of the starting position of each field. This is one area that `awk` isn't the greatest at (iterating over each character in a record and picking indexes based on the current state of the read). It's' doable, but gets long quick. The `FIELDWIDTHS` are set before the records are read -- so that isn't an option.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the [answer of David C. Rankin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73441698/8344060), the usage of `FIELDWIDTHS`, a GNU extension, is the answer. See the section [Processing Fixed-Width Data](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Fixed-width-data) of the GNU awk manual. The width of your FIELDS is actually defined in the second line.

The idea is to store the header in memory, parse the second line, define FIELDSWITHS and parse the full file:

```
awk 'BEGIN{OFS="|"}
     (FNR==1){ header=$0; next }
     (FNR==2){ n=split($0,a,"[.]")
               for(i=1;i<=n;++i) s = s length(a[i])+1 " "
               FIELDWIDTHS=s; $0=header
     }
     { $1=$1 }1' file
```

Based on the given input, this returns:

```
DISTRIBUTION       |MINIMUM SYSTEM REQUIREMENTS          |BASED ON         |IMAGE SIZE               |LATEST RELEASE YEAR     |FOUNDER
Absolute Linux     |CPU: Intel/AMD 64bit RAM: 64 MB      |Slackware        |                         |2020                    |Absolute Linux Team
Alpine Linux       |RAM: 128MB                           |BusyBox, musl    |                         |2022                    |LEAF Project members
antiX              |CPU: Intel/AMD X86, RAM 256MB        |                 |700 MB Base, 1GB Full    |2020                    |Anticapitalista
```

for a POSIX compliant analogue, see Ed Morton's solution!

Comment: If you change `$0=header` to `save=$0; $0=header; $1=$1; print; $0=save` then you can also print the `---` line.

Comment: If the header separator is required, have a look at the comment of @EdMorton. This shows you how to implement it.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I've tried with a sample file that has 11 fields and 50 records and prints output but without the `|`, not sure what happens.

Answer (score 2):

Using any awk:

```
$ cat tst.awk
NR == 1 {
    hdr = $0
    next
}
NR == 2 {
    split($0,parts,/[.]/)
    for ( i=1; i in parts; i++ ) {
        poss[i] = poss[i-1] + length(parts[i]) +1
    }
    prt(hdr)
}
{ prt($0) }
function prt(rec,       i) {
    for ( i=1; i in poss; i++ ) {
        rec = substr(rec,1,poss[i]-1) "|" substr(rec,poss[i]+1)
    }
    print rec
}
```

```
$ LC_ALL=C awk -f tst.awk file
DISTRIBUTION      |MINIMUM SYSTEM REQUIREMENTS         |BASED ON        |IMAGE SIZE              |LATEST RELEASE YEAR    |FOUNDER
------------------|------------------------------------|-- -------------|------------------------|-----------------------|--------------------
Absolute Linux    |CPU: Intel/AMD 64bit RAM: 64 MB     |Slackware       |                        |2020                   |Absolute Linux Team
Alpine Linux      |RAM: 128MB                          |BusyBox, musl   |                        |2022                   |LEAF Project members
antiX             |CPU: Intel/AMD X86, RAM 256MB       |                |700 MB Base, 1GB Full   |2020                   |Anticapitalista
```

The above identifies the position of every `.` in the `---.---` line then replaces whatever character is at that position with `|` in every line.

Comment: The method provided here and in  [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73441903/8344060) are essentially the same. The difference is that Ed Morton implemented the functionality of GNU extension `FIELDWIDTHS` directly using standard awk. Consequently, this solution is superior as it can be used with any version of awk on any Linux/Unix operating system that has a version of `awk` installed.

Comment: @kvantour thanks. Beyond not requiring GNU awk and not hard-coding field widths, the main difference in functionality with this solution is I'm not changing FS or $0 and not using any individual fields so a) awk doesn't have to do field splitting, b) awk doesn't have to rebuild $0 (though I'm doing that manually anyway), and c) if the OP does want to do anything with all the fields using default or any other FS, they can still do that just by setting FS however they like.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Not sure why trying in a sample file that has 11 fields and 50 records, I get `line:15: (FILENAME=input.txt FNR=25) warning: Invalid multibyte data detected. There may be a mismatch between your data and your locale
`

Comment: Your data contains non-ASCII characters somewhere. Instead of `awk '...'` do `LC_ALL=C awk '...'` (with `LC_ALL=C awk` on the same line or `export LC_ALL=C` earlier) to discard those. I edited my answer to show that.

Comment: @EdMorton Thanks for answer. I've tried with your updated code, in this case sending `LC_ALL=C awk '..' input`, error doesn't appear anymore and I see the `|` in output, but if I send the output to a file, for example `LC_ALL=C awk '...' input > output`, in output doesn't have the `|`. Is weird.

Comment: @RasecMalkic not weird - impossible :-). You're doing something wrong but without seeing exactly the code you're running we can't help you debug it. If you edit your question to show exactly the code you're running, the input file contents, and the output file contents then we can probably help you.

Answer (score 0):

Would you please try a solution which finds the header positions as you have first tried:

```
#!/bin/bash

headers=("DISTRIBUTION" "MINIMUM SYSTEM REQUIREMENTS" "BASED ON" "IMAGE SIZE" "LATEST RELEASE YEAR" "FOUNDER")

awk -v hd="$(IFS=,; echo "${headers[*]}")" '                            # "hd" is a string of header names separated by commas
    BEGIN {
        len = split(hd, header, /,/)                                    # retrieve header names in an array "header"
    }
    NR==1 {                                                             # process the header line
        for (i = 2; i <= len; i++) pos[index($0, header[i]) - 1]        # an array "pos" holds the positions to replace the character
    }
    {
        for (i in pos) $0 = substr($0, 1, i - 1) "|" substr($0, i + 1)  # put "|" on the positions in "pos"
    }
1' input.txt
```

Output:

```
DISTRIBUTION      |MINIMUM SYSTEM REQUIREMENTS         |BASED ON        |IMAGE SIZE              |LATEST RELEASE YEAR    |FOUNDER
------------------|------------------------------------|-- -------------|------------------------|-----------------------|--------------------
Absolute Linux    |CPU: Intel/AMD 64bit RAM: 64 MB     |Slackware       |                        |2020                   |Absolute Linux Team
Alpine Linux      |RAM: 128MB                          |BusyBox, musl   |                        |2022                   |LEAF Project members
antiX             |CPU: Intel/AMD X86, RAM 256MB       |                |700 MB Base, 1GB Full   |2020                   |Anticapitalista
```